# MVC kendo window - Get Data from JavaScript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I have this kendo window in my app

```
Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("copyStructure")
    .Title("Copy Structure")
    .Content("Loading...")
    .LoadContentFrom("CopyStructure", "NewXmlLayout") // <-- here*
    .Draggable(false)
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Actions(s => s.Custom(""))
    .Events(e => e.Open("openWindow").Close("closeWindow"))
```

And I am trying to pass data to the action in the LoadContentFrom() which is returned by a JavaScript function, but I don't know how to do it. I can pass data  like this:

```
.LoadContentFrom("CopyStructure", "NewXmlLayout", new { type= "INPUT" })
```

But is not what I'm looking for.

The JS function:

```
function getInfo() {
        return { type: "INPUT" };
    };
```

My controller:

```
 public ActionResult CopyStructure(string type)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you replace `"NewXmlLayout"` with `getInfo()`?  What do you mean by "not what I'm looking for"?

Comment: `"NewXmlLayout"` is my controller and `CopyStructure` is my Action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really need to access your data via the JavaScript `getInfo()` function, then the way to do this is to define the Window as you are doing but don't set the content until you open the window. When opening the Window, use `jQuery.ajax()` to call `CopyResult`, passing the results of `getInfo()` into the data parameter.

In your Razor, take out `LoadContentFrom` add an event handler for the `Open` event:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("copyStructure")
    // Omitted for brevity
    ...
    .Events(e => e.Open("copyStructure_Open"))
)
```

And in your handler in JavaScript, call `$.ajax` and in the `success` callback, call the `content` method on the Window object passing the returned `data` as the parameter:

```
function copyStructure_Open(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CopyStructure", "NewXmlLayout")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: getInfo(),
        success: function(data) {
            e.sender.content(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Beware to only send what's required for the window content, and not a full page (DOCTYPE, html, head, body) - see this documentation from Telerik: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/window/overview#loading-window-content-via-ajax

Comment: thank you, i was pulling my hair off with loadcontentfrom with mvc partial view while i forgot to set layout to null